# Has a way to enable Microsoft Authenticator in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In my project, this a fundamental part of project. Windows Hello for Bussiness and MS Authenticator is secure and easily to use, the goal here is enable this in Azure B2C SUSI to increment safety and provide a fast way to SignIn for user.

The point is, has a way to do that in B2C? Replace normal password to a paswordless way authentiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility to achieve Multi factor authentication using Authenticator app. It is documented and a sample is provider here: Azure AD B2C: [TOTP multi-factor authentication](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp)

With **Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C**, you can integrate `TOTP-based Multi-Factor Authentication` so that you can add a second layer of security to sign-up and sign-in experiences in your consumer-facing applications. This requires using `custom policy` and `custom REST API endpoint`. If you already created sign-up and sign-in policies, you can still enable Multi-Factor Authentication.

**Below is the user auth flow using TOTP:**

[image]

At this time, MS does not support primary Auth using Authenticator for B2C. You can request this via the [Azure AD B2C forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c) in feedback.azure.com

Answer (score 0):

SMS and Phone verification are the options available as of now.